# Horizontal scrolling section in the center of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im new to this so i hope someone can help!

I want to make a horizontal scrolling section (by click) like on this page: http://www.ritchiejacobs.be.

The section has to be responsive, the height should be auto and the container should be in the center.

I didn't came any further then this: jsfiddle.net/fwqekgk8/

Thank you!

Comment: You could achieve that by using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) using the option `autoScrolling:false`.

Answer (score 0):

They use a list, not a section. Maybe u can try a list for it!